# IIS returning default Error HTML instead of JSON, as instructed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-5

I made a custom `Attribute` for certain endpoints in my ASP.NET MVC project, that instructs the server to return a JSON object, instead of handling the errors the usual way. The Attribute looks like this:

```
public class AjaxErrorHandler : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusDescription =
                filterContext.Exception.Message.Replace('\r', ' ').Replace('\n', ' ');
            filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
            {
                Data = new { errorMessage = filterContext.Exception.Message }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I debug the solution locally, it works just fine, and returns the following on error:

```
{"errorMessage":"Error message goes here"}
```

But when I deploy the solution to my production server, the server consistantly returns the following HTML:

```
 #content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
 .content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
 -->
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id = "header" >< h1 > Server Error</h1></div>
 <div id = "content" >
     < div class="content-container"><fieldset>
 <h2>500 - Internal server error.</h2>
 <h3>There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

What configuration of the web project am I missing here, to make the server honor the instruction to return the JSON object?

Comment: Check both web.config setting between local and production machine. Did you spot certain differences?

Comment: Same config file. Only difference is the connection string to the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this before with IIS.

From memory, you could try this:

- Open the IIS Mgr
- Select the website in question
- Double click error pages icon
- Click edit feature settings on the right hand side
- Change the setting to detailed errors for local and custom error pages for remote requests
- Try the site again

Think that was how I got around it in the past